# How to keep track of non empty field in Joda date buffer

Tags: java, jodatime

I'm writing a set of objects that should be able to alter fields in a [Joda Time](http://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CH8QFjAA&url=http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/&ei=HxCmT4qyBuPl4QSq6PiGCQ&usg=AFQjCNH25QvdckCfXWVVnS-A2r46o4wp6g) MutableDateTime instance.

Each object is applied in sequence to the buffer, and when all that set is applied, a complete valid MutableDateTime will be built.

Each instance have to be able to know which date time fields has already been set by other instances in the set.

I get stucked because I get following problems:

1. How to create the MutableDateTime instance with empty values in all
   date time fields in order to use it as the initial value to build?
2. How could I know if some field of MutableDateTime has been set?

MutableDateTime internally keep track it's data in a long instance field initialized to number of milliseconds elapsed from start of era to now. It thus has all field already set to some value.

Do you know if MutableDateTime has some concept of an empty value?

**Edit:**

as I show in my response, I develop a solution using a manager class as Vladimir suggested.

Comment: You mean joda, right ;-)

Comment: I'd be interested in Yoda's solution for a date/time API :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create "Manager" class to remember fields which was already set. It should throw exception if user tries to retrieve instance of `MutableDateTime` before all fields was set.

And if you always set all fields for `MutableDateTime` then [1] is not important (values will be overwriten).

Answer (score 1):

I finally changed my initial design, and I implemented it exactly as Vadim Ponomarev suggested. Since each field type in Joda buffer has a corresponding DateTimeFieldType instance, I use a private Set object to keep track of the fields present.

The code below show how I've done:

```
 private final Set<DateTimeFieldType> fieldTypes = Sets.newHashSet();

    /**
 * Allow to set to or reset one of the DateTimeFieldType fields 
 * @param fieldType the DateTimeFieldType field to change
 * @param value the value to set it
 */
    public void changeField(DateTimeFieldType fieldType, boolean value) {
        if (value)
            fieldTypes.add(fieldType);
        else
            fieldTypes.remove(fieldType);
    }

    /**
 * Check if one of the DateTimeFieldType is present in this set.
 * @param fieldType The field type to check for presence.
 * @return true if the DateTimeFieldType is present, otherwise false
 */
    public boolean isFieldSet(DateTimeFieldType fieldType) {
        return !fieldTypes.contains(fieldType);
    }
```

I've also added some utility methods allowing to change all fields for the date and all fields for the time at once. This could be useful in client to code to easy a common operation on date field sets.

```
/**
 * Allow to set the fields that build the time part
 * of a date time
 * <p/>
 *
 * @param value value to set the DateTime fields
 */
    public void changeTimeFields(boolean value) {

        changeField(DateTimeFieldType.hourOfDay(), value);
        changeField(DateTimeFieldType.minuteOfHour(), value);
    }


/**
 * Allow to set the fields that build the date part
 * of a date time
 * <p/>
 *
 * @param value value to set the DateTime fields
 */
    public void changeDateFields(boolean value) {
        changeField(DateTimeFieldType.dayOfMonth(), value);
        changeField(DateTimeFieldType.monthOfYear(), value);
        changeField(DateTimeFieldType.yearOfEra(), value);
    }
```

And finally, I also added some method to query if all date fields are set and if all time fields are set:

```
/**
 * Allow to check if the DateTimeFieldType fields that build the 
 * date part of a datetime has been set in this instance.
 * <p/>
 *
 * @return true if date part has yet to be applied to
 * the instance, false otherwise
 */
    public boolean isDateSet() {
        return fieldTypes.contains(DateTimeFieldType.dayOfMonth()) &&
                fieldTypes.contains(DateTimeFieldType.monthOfYear()) &&
                fieldTypes.contains(DateTimeFieldType.yearOfEra());
    }

    /**
 * Allow to check if the DateTimeFieldType fields that build the 
 * time part of a datetime has been set in this instance.
 * <p/>
 *
 * @return true if time part has yet to be applied to
 * the instance, false otherwise
 */
    public boolean isTimeSet() {
        return fieldTypes.contains(DateTimeFieldType.minuteOfHour()) &&
                fieldTypes.contains(DateTimeFieldType.hourOfDay());

    }
```

I finally made it a DateTimeFieldTypeSet class. I think it encapsulate well a common concept that is lacking in Joda classes. I hope it can be useful to some one else too.